# Restrict RDP Collection By IP

Tags: rds, rdweb

I have an RDS server that serves applications via RDWeb. Users are added to Organisational Units that represent the customer, and each application is linked to an OU so that the users in Customer1 only see their version of the application.

Now customer2 wants to restrict access by IP address. If I add firewall rules to the network perimeter it will lock out all the other customers. Is there anything way I could say "only allow access to the application for customer2 if the requesting IP is in range …"

Comment: Hi, in my understanding, no, but I know in xenapp you can set user policy that restrict ressource by IP range.